# Exception printing only one word

Tags: python, exception

I have part of a class that looks like this:

```
def set_new_mode(self,mode):
    try:
        #this will fail, since self.keithley is never initialized
        print self.keithley
        self.keithley.setzerocheck(on=True)
        self.keithley.selectmode(mode,nplc=6)
        self.keithley.setzerocheck(on=False) #keithcontrol class will 
        #automatically turn on zero correction when zchk is disabled
        self.mode = mode
        self.print_to_log('\nMode set to %s' % self.mode)
    except Exception as e:
        self.print_to_log('\nERROR:set_new_mode: %s' % e)
        print e
```

As part of some testing of error handling, I've tried calling the `set_new_mode` function without first initializing the class variable `self.keithley`.  In this case, I would expect that the `print self.keithley` statement would raise an `AttributeError: keithgui instance has no attribute 'keithley'`.  However, the `print e` and `self.print_to_log('\nERROR:set_new_mode: %s' % e)` indicate that `e` contains only the word "keithley".

Changing `print e` to `print type(e)` reveals that `e` still has the type AttributeError, but the variable no longer contains any useful information about the exception.  Why?  And how do I return `e` to its expected form?

Edit:  Here is a MEW to reproduce the error.  **To reproduce the error, start the GUI, change the mode to something other than VOLT and click the update button.**

```
import Tkinter

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg


class keithgui(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        #we are not initially connected to the keithley
        self.connected = False
        self.pauseupdate = False

        #set up frames to distribute widgets
        #MASTER FRAME
        self.mframe = Tkinter.Frame(self,bg='green')
        self.mframe.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill='both',expand=True)
        #LEFT AND RIGHT FRAMES
        self.Lframe = Tkinter.Frame(self.mframe,bg='red',borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        self.Lframe.pack(side='left',fill='both',expand=True)
        self.Rframe = Tkinter.Frame(self.mframe,bg='blue',borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        self.Rframe.pack(side='right',fill='both',expand=False)

        #create the log text widget to keep track of what we did last
        #also give it a scrollbar...
        scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(master=self.Lframe)
        scrollbar.pack(side=Tkinter.RIGHT,anchor='n')
        self.logtext = Tkinter.Text(master=self.Lframe,height=3,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.logtext.yview)
        self.logtext.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,anchor='w',fill='both')

        #Button to update all settings
        updatebutton = Tkinter.Button(master=self.Rframe,text='Update',command=self.update_all_params)
        updatebutton.grid(column=2,row=0)


        #Option menu & label to select mode of the Keithley
        modes = ['VOLT','CHAR','CURR']
        modelabel = Tkinter.Label(master=self.Rframe,text='Select Mode:')
        modelabel.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='W') 
        self.mode = 'VOLT'
        self.modevar = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.modevar.set(self.mode)
        modeselectmenu = Tkinter.OptionMenu(self.Rframe,self.modevar,*modes)
        modeselectmenu.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='W')

    def print_to_log(self,text,loc=Tkinter.END):
        self.logtext.insert(loc,text)
        self.logtext.see(Tkinter.END)



    def update_all_params(self):
        self.set_refresh_rate()
        if self.modevar.get() != self.mode:
            self.set_new_mode(self.modevar.get())
        else:
            self.print_to_log('\nAlready in mode %s' % self.mode)

    def set_refresh_rate(self):
        try:
            self.refreshrate = np.float(self.refreshrateentryvar.get())
            self.print_to_log('\nRefresh rate set to %06.3fs' % self.refreshrate)
        except Exception as e:
            self.print_to_log('\nERROR:set_referesh_rate: %s' % e)

    def set_new_mode(self,mode):
        try:
            print self.keithley
            self.keithley.setzerocheck(on=True)
            self.keithley.selectmode(mode,nplc=6)
            self.keithley.setzerocheck(on=False) #keithcontrol class will 
            #automatically turn on zero correction when zchk is disabled
            self.mode = mode
            self.print_to_log('\nMode set to %s' % self.mode)
        except Exception as e:
            self.print_to_log('\nERROR:set_new_mode: %s' % e)
            print e
            print type(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = keithgui(None)
    app.title('Keithley GUI')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you provide minimal code to reproduce the problem, so we can see if we see the same issue?

Comment: You may want to check out the `logging` module - in particular, `logging.exception()` is super useful

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I get `ERROR:set_new_mode: Fnord instance has no attribute 'keithley'
Fnord instance has no attribute 'keithley'`

Comment: Do you have a `__getattribute__` in your class?

Comment: @WayneWerner - The print_to_log function is actually a function to print to a Tkinter text log in a GUI (which is what the class actually us).  But I agree that the logging module is great!

Comment: Ah, that was essential - subclassing from `tk.Tk` does it.

Comment: @MarkRansom - I don't have one in my class, but Tk does have one, (which I believe should be inherited by my class, if you look at the mwe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Fnord(tk.Tk):
    def set_new_mode(self,mode):
        try:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            #this will fail, since self.keithley is never initialized
            print self.keithley

Fnord().set_new_mode('whatever')
```

And then start stepping through with `s`, you'll see that there's a `__getattr__` function on your window. I'm looking through to see what causes the problem now, but that's effectively gonna be your answer.

---

Following the call stack, it led me to a call `self.tk = _tkinter.create`, which eventually led me get [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eb8294f4412f3488ae4804d67ae5bda3031306ac/Modules/clinic/_tkinter.c.h#L555). Ultimately what this boils down to is that the exception is happening in C-territory, so it's producing a different `AttributeError` message.

Comment: So in this case, it seems that the solution is to check for the existence of ```self.keithley``` first via ```hasattr(self,'keithley')```, and then raise an AttributeError if it hasn't been initialized yet (with some sort of useful error message for the user).


I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer, since it seems that this is cause by the implementation of Tk, rather than my code, so the workaround is something like what I posted above.

Comment: You could always add a `getattr` in *your* code, and then let it percolate up the stack. However, why not just set `keithley` to something reasonable in the beginning? [Temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) should be avoided if possible.

Comment: 'keithley' is actually a class that contains the machinery for python to talk to an instrument via RS232. The purpose of the GUI is to display/manipulate the data drawn from the keithley.  The issue is that sometimes there are multiple keithleys connected to a machine, and the GUI wants to connect to a specific one set by the user at connect time (so can't define ahead of time). I could do something like set ```self.keithley = None``` and check ```if self.keithley == None: raise ...```, but isn't that basically the same as checking if it exists? Is that how you would recommend implementing it?

Comment: Why would you allow them to even change the mode in the first place if they haven't connected to a particular keithley? It seems like you'd want to check for the keithley's that are available and either a) connect to the first one you find or b) connect to nothing and wait for them to connect to one. But until they have connected, any kind of configuration buttons or entry should be disabled.